# Typescript: How to constrain property selection by generic parameter's properties and additional type?

Tags: typescript

Example of constraining property selection by Generic Parameter's `T` properties only:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  locations: number[];
}

function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key];
}

const p1: Person = { name : "Foo", age: 55, locations: [1,2,3,4] };
const name = getProperty(p1, "locations"); // Output: [1,2,3,4]
```

What I want to achieve now is constraining the object key `K` selection not only to `keyof T` but also `K` to be of a specific type eg: Array. Example of usage:

```
const name = getProperty<Array<number>>(p1, "name");      // Should fail as name is not Array<number>
const name = getProperty<Array<number>>(p1, "locations"); // Should succeed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most I can achieve : [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOygXigbwFBSlQEMBbCALikWHgEtUBzAbnyiIYsIFcSAjBFgQA2yAMZFgtNIkqoe-eAG0AuiwC+uXADMuqUZLRQOwGPGSR4oADwAVADRQAqlAgAPYBFQATRFBuKAawgQZC0-ZQcAaRd3Tx8oAGUuXhtwCFsHRwA+TETk1MgMpyysgApkXgArSnsoIJBKetCoSIBKSmc8AngIYC54dArKwOC2X10A1GQAd3QiXyawm2Uxp3VNUEg8lLSrACF5iAcAYTQvWgNUHKwYWlEA-cOHLoIoRUjR+jrg5oPECGUlD+EHewRWbg83l8p28Fyk6AA-C1RrIIAA3BC4NQjEJhYHKLIsXAAemJUAAoq5SGAhBBfABaek5AASyAx8CghgAIlBgMgqBBoEkdlseoguEJgCSyQALYDAMAyUlkc48AB0omQJGJXiItCEIEqiGJmzpojoYGA9PNEAkEHpRGtZzhaHpvEOXnp4t4-ytpsQ9IAnF5AwAGABMoltAFZeAAOUS4U1QHlYYUFdJwJBoBxyPgIQnSqCMkulsvlzSa1DUKBgACMlCzKHQWGwhFI0EoAHIAGLIZBdhzsTjR6MOETiS4yN51uzhuwAZjsABYVmoiaTEjLkBKvFAtHqhKstP2oLRfFNgGf0E20LgqzW0UR4HXcsZTOYEKBSvWHF2TwOrRMK8BCaJuCTbru+6HqsxBkGeF7IFezTJgAgvA8BECAVh5goORfLeqD3tIV5PvA4Zvr0H4WNYhEOOhmHYbhBZlL+UBdnBEBdkBIFgWSEE7kIe7iqIUYQHu8ztvB57XrACDNsR1akc+C6USYZg0SAP6zuxnHccBrx8VugnCVwomChJvgThI8K+DJBHyYYRDeAhbDcPmSjKIpj7PsuanUV+2F0e5CgqKxOldtZU76VARkCVBIliZZbAcK5DnZnMLkyUQIWYg+ynwNG-kaYFVjBcx8DhX+w4xXFkFCdB+qrMOaU3o5mV7jJl5udQdCMN5BUAGzFZ+lhBe1Di9fQDBVexNU8ZW0jILSaoiAwpRkXWQHectECrcg61keG20Prt+2HSpJ1LSta0bb5V3Vmdt1kdGD0oDdB13fAg3bUAA)

Using [this medium article soluce](https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c) :

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;
```

---

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  locations: number[];
}

function getProperty<T, U extends T[keyof T], K extends SubType<T, U> = SubType<T, U>>(obj: T, key: keyof K): U {
  return obj[key as unknown as keyof T] as U;
}

type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;

// Examples --> Hover on D to see SubType result
// https://medium.com/dailyjs/typescript-create-a-condition-based-subset-types-9d902cea5b8c
type D = SubType<Person, number>;
// --------------------

const p1: Person = { name : 'Foo', age: 55, locations: [1,2,3,4] };

// Should fail as foo is not in Person
const var1 = getProperty(p1, 'foo');     

// Should fail as name is not of type Array<number> in Person
const var2 = getProperty<Person, Array<number>>(p1, 'name');    

// Should succeed as name is in Person
const var3 = getProperty(p1, 'name');    

// Should succeed as locations is in Person and is a number[]
const var4 = getProperty<Person, number[]>(p1, 'locations'); 

// Should succeed as age is in Person and is a number
const var5 = getProperty<Person, number>(p1, 'age'); 

// Should fail as age is in Person and is not a string
const var6 = getProperty<Person, string>(p1, 'age'); 

console.log(var1);
console.log(var2);
console.log(var3);
console.log(var4);
console.log(var5);
console.log(var6);
```

Comment: Wow outstanding example. I never understand where are the limits between inline type constraints within the generic parameter area `<>`, and a separated type. I guess once its separated it becomes much cleaner to read. Many thanks!